# Null<> Number displays nothing even if for id we have null in one and number in other

Tags: sql

Sorry if this is very basic.
Here is what i noticed
Here are the tables:

```
Table1                         Table2
ID     Value                 ID   Value
1      (null)                 1     0
2      2                      2     2
3      (null)                 3     3
```

So i used the following statement:

```
Select T1.ID,T1.Value,T2.value
from
Table1 T1,
Table2 T2
where 
T1.ID=T2.ID
and T1.Value<>T2.Value;
```

I was expecting the output to show 1,3 ID but it showed nothing not i am confused suppose i want to see all values when one table has null for other table value how can i do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem is that comparisons to NULL always result in FALSE, except for `IS NULL`.  So the clause should be:

```
where T1.ID=T2.ID and
      coalesce(T1.Value, t2.value - 1) <> coalesce(T2.Value, t1.value -1);
```

Or something that matches the NULL values.

By the way, you should also use proper join syntax.  So, the query should look more like:

```
Select T1.ID,T1.Value,T2.value
from Table1 T1 join
     Table2 T2
     on T1.ID=T2.ID and
        ((T1.Value <> T2.Value) or
         (t1.value is not null and t2.value is null) or
         (t1.value is null and t2.value is not null)
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` because you want to find non matching values.

```
Select  t1.ID,T1.Value,T2.value
from    Table1 T1
        LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
            ON T1.ID=T2.ID AND
                t1.value = t2.value
where  t2.value IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9a28/1)

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 2):

```
Select T1.ID,T1.Value,T2.value
from
Table1 T1,
Table2 T2
where 
T1.ID=T2.ID
and (T1.Value<>T2.Value OR (T1.Value IS NULL AND T2.Value IS NOT NULL) OR (T2.Value IS NULL AND T1.Value IS NOT NULL));
```

Answer (score 1):

Null values are special. You can do it with a complex query like

```
Select T1.ID,T1.Value,T2.value
  from
  Table1 T1,
  Table2 T2
  where 
  T1.ID=T2.ID
  and ((t1.value is null or t2.value is null)
       and !(t1.value is null and t2.value is null)
       or t1.value <> t2.value);
```

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20fc33/1)

Note that the syntax is going to be different, depending on the flavor of SQL that you are using.